# How to perform and interpret Redundancy Analysis (RDA)?

Tags: r, statistics

I generated a data.frame (database) where I have the arimetic average with water quality parameters, land use data and the associated monitoring stations over time.

I would like to know if the Redundancy Rnalysis(rda) could indicate whether the variation in land use affected the water quality in the same period? How could I organize my data to get this information?

water date: `pH`,`OD`,`DBO`,`N_Total`,`P_Total`,`Coli_Termo`,`Sol_Totais`,`Turbidez`,`IQA`

land use: `veg`,`crop`,`grass`,`city`,`soil`,`water`.

dput out of data

> ```
> structure(list(station = c("F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
> "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
> "F02", "F02", "F02", "F02", "F02", "F02", "F02", "F02", "F02", 
> "F02", "F02", "F02", "F02", "F02", "F03", "F03", "F03", "F03", 
> "F03", "F03", "F03", "F03", "F03", "F03", "F03", "F03", "F03", 
> "F03", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", 
> "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F05", "F05", "F05", 
> "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", 
> "F05", "F05", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", 
> "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06"), year = c("2005", 
> "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", 
> "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2005", "2006", "2007", 
> "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", 
> "2016", "2017", "2018", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", 
> "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", 
> "2018", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", 
> "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2005", 
> "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", 
> "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2005", "2006", "2007", 
> "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", 
> "2016", "2017", "2018"), pH = c(8.175, 8.8, 8.35, 8.18, 7.85, 
> 8.125, 7.65, 7.93333333333333, 8.2, 8.25, 8, 8.1, 8.225, 8.2, 
> 8.15, 8.25, 7.9, 8.12, 7.85, 8.075, 7.675, 7.93333333333333, 
> 8.15, 8.25, 8, 8.125, 8.175, 8.26666666666667, 7.9, 7.8, 7.23333333333333, 
> 8.1, 8.08333333333333, 8.1, 7.9, 8.03333333333333, 8.25, 8.3, 
> 7.85, 8.125, 8.1, 8.26666666666667, 7.79230769230769, 7.8375, 
> 7.38, 11.104347826087, 7.84333333333333, 7.93, 7.785, 7.81333333333333, 
> 7.92, 8.05, 7.785, 7.975, 7.865, 8.04666666666667, 8, 8.15, 7.95, 
> 7.68, 7.66666666666667, 7.6, 7.65, 8, 8.05, 8.35, 7.875, 7.95, 
> 8, 8, 7.825, 8, 7.625, 7.52, 7.3, 7.6, 7.325, 7.5, 7.75, 7.9, 
> 7.475, 7.7, 7.475, 7.63333333333333), OD = c(8.225, 7.05, 7.85, 
> 6.28, 5.81666666666667, 7.95, 6.85, 7.23333333333333, 7.45, 8.25, 
> 8.05, 7.75, 7.925, 8.2, 8.65, 7.2, 7.45, 6.58, 6.68333333333333, 
> 8.125, 7.3, 7.5, 7.6, 8.3, 8.375, 8.075, 8.125, 8.46666666666667, 
> 5.96666666666667, 3.6, 3.56666666666667, 4.92, 5.41666666666667, 
> 6.8, 6.875, 6.8, 5.2, 6.9, 7.625, 6.975, 7.075, 8.26666666666667, 
> 6.08461538461538, 4.5375, 3.16, 4.33478260869565, 5.43666666666667, 
> 6.18, 6.325, 6.04, 4.71, 6.47, 6.545, 6.31, 6.705, 7.65333333333333, 
> 7.8, 8.7, 8.225, 7.32, 6.8, 6.5, 7.15, 7.6, 7.45, 8, 8.15, 7.975, 
> 7.875, 6.66666666666667, 7.325, 7.05, 6.8, 5.52, 5.7, 6.5, 6.65, 
> 6.53333333333333, 7.6, 7.4, 6.775, 6.775, 5.875, 5.53333333333333
> ), DBO = c(1, 1, 0.5, 0.8, 1.66666666666667, 1.75, 1.25, NaN, 
> 1, 2.5, 1.5, 1.5, 4.25, 4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.25, 1.4, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 
> NaN, 0.5, 1, 2.5, 1.25, 4.25, 3.33333333333333, 3, 7.5, 9, 1, 
> 1.66666666666667, 2, 1.25, NaN, 2, 5.5, 3.25, 1, 3.5, 3, 1.92307692307692, 
> 1.75, 2.53333333333333, 2.63636363636364, 2.36666666666667, 3.1, 
> 1.8, NaN, 4.2, 3.5, 3.45, 1.85, 4.1, 6.33333333333333, 0.25, 
> 0.5, 0.75, 0.8, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, NaN, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 0.75, 4.25, 
> 3.66666666666667, 1, 1, 0, 3, 0.8, 1.5, 1, NaN, 3.5, 1, 1.75, 
> 0.75, 3, 3.33333333333333), N_Total = c(0.515, 0.335, 0.68, 0.502, 
> 0.698333333333333, 0.3, 0.32, NaN, 0.215, 1.1, 0.92, 0.725, 0.9225, 
> 0.43, 0.61, 0.395, 0.38, 0.56, 0.525, 0.27, 0.345, NaN, 0.265, 
> 1.05, 0.8325, 1.19, 1.1225, 0.353333333333333, 30.3433333333333, 
> 51.24, 59.9066666666667, 1.02, 1.56, 0.895, 0.39, NaN, 0.485, 
> 0.525, 3.725, 2.155, 1.1775, 0.89, 4.76769230769231, 2.89375, 
> 8.448, 11.5065217391304, 2.69, 3.7015, 3.586, NaN, 5.269, 3.819, 
> 10.1835, 2.5935, 3.7665, 2.56733333333333, 0.3725, 0.4, 0.3875, 
> 0.382, 0.321666666666667, 0.335, 0.285, NaN, 0.175, 0.23, 0.7325, 
> 0.515, 0.355, 0.266666666666667, 0.7475, 0.445, 0.4525, 0.45, 
> 0.706, 0.335, 0.315, NaN, 0.185, 0.215, 1.045, 0.88, 0.44, 0.21
> ), P_Total = c(0.0515, 0.063, 0.0555, 0.2602, 0.130833333333333, 
> 0.061, 0.13675, NaN, 0.023, 0.6195, 0.1225, 0.056, 0.2055, 0.0596666666666667, 
> 0.0415, 0.0815, 0.108, 0.1658, 0.157166666666667, 0.08375, 0.0625, 
> NaN, 0.0215, 0.1015, 0.06925, 0.06225, 0.08325, 0.0596666666666667, 
> 1.287, 1.818, 1.89566666666667, 0.2514, 0.292166666666667, 0.179, 
> 0.0925, NaN, 0.0225, 0.043, 0.07125, 0.13225, 0.08475, 0.0596666666666667, 
> 0.897384615384615, 0.24375, 0.534533333333333, 1.04039130434783, 
> 0.659333333333333, 0.39115, 1.37155, NaN, 0.5343, 0.3318, 0.7041, 
> 0.49155, 0.34085, 0.274866666666667, 0.07725, 0.065, 0.0835, 
> 0.2426, 0.149333333333333, 0.07925, 0.05675, NaN, 0.012, 0.0325, 
> 0.06475, 0.149, 0.08325, 0.0596666666666667, 0.013, 0.061, 0.1165, 
> 0.124, 0.1614, 0.07925, 0.06325, NaN, 0.017, 0.023, 0.0395, 0.059, 
> 0.08325, 0.0596666666666667), Coli_Termo = c(337.5, 435, 150, 
> 590, 569.666666666667, 25325, 1572.5, NaN, 510, 820, 4530, 413.75, 
> 457, 450, 195, 890, 132.5, 624, 5019.16666666667, 16375, 1404.5, 
> NaN, 104, 175, 3292.5, 1785, 204.5, 1393.33333333333, 13740, 
> 36000, 39633.3333333333, 8240, 15583.3333333333, 355200, 2407.5, 
> NaN, 420, 8395, 1937.5, 9375, 12675, 9966.66666666667, 14048.4615384615, 
> 8012.5, 14114.6666666667, 125192.608695652, 50134.3333333333, 
> 60447, 9779.5, NaN, 15668, 9481, 108957, 9336.94117647059, 7528, 
> 7295.33333333333, 147.5, 1220, 152.5, 284, 233.333333333333, 
> 16075, 1405, NaN, 330, 330, 200, 91.25, 88.5, 47.6666666666667, 
> 700, 515, 807.5, 964, 1476, 16075, 725, NaN, 300, 410, 512.5, 
> 395, 254.5, 89.6666666666667), Sol_Totais = c(187.5, 191.5, 326, 
> 267.8, 252.333333333333, 245, 239.75, NaN, 214, 691, 267.5, 241.75, 
> 239.5, 241, 229, 211, 343, 228.4, 241.333333333333, 266.75, 218.25, 
> NaN, 200.5, 223, 223, 239.25, 238, 233.333333333333, 292, 661, 
> 1216, 2345.8, 340, 382.5, 322, NaN, 321, 356.5, 341.75, 348, 
> 287.25, 283, 283.461538461538, 241.25, 512.333333333333, 373.913043478261, 
> 332.033333333333, 377.25, 323, NaN, 334.9, 354.2, 338.25, 342.75, 
> 318.7, 357.066666666667, 214.5, 191, 324.25, 225, 201.333333333333, 
> 265.75, 228.75, NaN, 212.5, 253.5, 228.75, 248.25, 227, 217, 
> 231, 193, 330, 247.4, 226, 265.75, 255, NaN, 205.5, 248.5, 253.25, 
> 249.25, 246.75, 246), Turbidez = c(5.7625, 4.46, 3.81, 8.408, 
> 23.7116666666667, 5.255, 38.2075, 5.06666666666667, 4.68, 210.65, 
> 26.655, 4.48, 9.385, 3.49333333333333, 3.435, 1.975, 2.04, 24.036, 
> 12.8933333333333, 1.86, 2.26, 0.666666666666667, 1.36, 1.75, 
> 9.44, 2.2325, 2.68, 2.20333333333333, 4.76333333333333, 4.235, 
> 68.7966666666667, 5.344, 24.38, 147.0825, 3.575, 3.06666666666667, 
> 0.465, 6.65, 2.66, 2.1525, 19.9475, 2.06, 4.11384615384615, 3.735, 
> 46.8326666666667, 6.01304347826087, 28.0713793103448, 45.0625, 
> 3.5335, 4.02666666666667, 9.189, 18.09, 4.629, 3.58, 60.922, 
> 3.678, 3.2425, 1.115, 1.9225, 1.096, 2.405, 2.305, 1.6, 0.233333333333333, 
> 0.725, 3.5, 1.995, 1.0725, 0.9375, 1.83, 4.98, 4.565, 2.5525, 
> 1.906, 6.714, 2.305, 16.3275, 2.73333333333333, 1.775, 2.45, 
> 1.15, 1.1875, 0.89, 0.363333333333333), IQA = c(76, 72.5, 77, 
> 68.8, 67.6666666666667, 63.75, 67, NaN, 75, 59.5, 66.75, 77.5, 
> 72.25, 73, 78.75, 74.5, 77, 72.8, 66.8333333333333, 63.75, 73.75, 
> NaN, 80.5, 76.5, 70.75, 73, 77, 72.3333333333333, 51, 29, 25.6666666666667, 
> 56.6, 51.5, 55.25, 67.5, NaN, 66.5, 61, 66, 61, 59.5, 64.6666666666667, 
> 59.3076923076923, 56.625, 46.9333333333333, 47.8695652173913, 
> 53.2333333333333, 51.95, 60.35, NaN, 54.7, 56.3, 56.5, 63.2352941176471, 
> 60.7, 62.2666666666667, 78.5, 76.5, 77.25, 72.2, 74, 60, 71.5, 
> NaN, 76.5, 74.5, 76.5, 81.25, 78.75, 79, 74.25, 73.5, 69, 65.8, 
> 63.8, 60, 70.5, NaN, 75, 75, 73.5, 75.25, 75.25, 75), veg = c(12281.5824712026, 
> 12334.3880617964, 12300.7089055909, 12274.5971647303, 12383.451523923, 
> 12421.0391254165, 12435.0928967714, 12375.1356828846, 12276.0108577068, 
> 12262.1234031727, 12201.4177635924, 12268.2771255411, 12249.9822752567, 
> 12292.2267477317, 7254.98919713131, 7366.50462545626, 7366.67094227702, 
> 7389.04055467032, 7437.93769997611, 7470.86843048818, 7479.35058834735, 
> 7464.04944083669, 7420.89022584739, 7430.86923509347, 7396.27533637373, 
> 7440.0998186461, 7458.47782734096, 7488.9138055415, 864.182200710528, 
> 930.625770607344, 943.8479578584, 953.328016642176, 973.286035134336, 
> 990.83245972536, 995.905122758784, 986.591380795776, 963.307025888256, 
> 949.336412943744, 933.03736450848, 933.4531565604, 934.367899074624, 
> 941.602680778032, 549.510775817472, 598.407921123264, 604.14585143976, 
> 610.216415397792, 622.191226493088, 634.082879178, 632.087077328784, 
> 626.18283019152, 604.727960312448, 592.171040344464, 577.784635348032, 
> 576.28778396112, 577.867793758416, 584.104674537216, 5577.10195081334, 
> 5602.54842439085, 5584.17041569598, 5591.48835580978, 5615.10534435883, 
> 5623.33802698685, 5617.18430461843, 5613.60849297192, 5595.39680109782, 
> 5617.76641349112, 5610.6147901981, 5649.86555989934, 5668.40988541498, 
> 5688.28474549675, 1244.96456185886, 1262.67730327066, 1259.43412526568, 
> 1261.76256075643, 1275.9826489321, 1282.88479699397, 1287.20903433394, 
> 1283.71638109781, 1281.63742083821, 1284.63112361203, 1282.55216335243, 
> 1304.09019164189, 1302.42702343421, 1306.41862713264), crop = c(113.178596532624, 
> 99.873250871184, 91.141617780864, 192.678036859728, 260.784774964224, 
> 280.410159814848, 311.927197350384, 410.303596834656, 530.716975070688, 
> 995.988281169168, 1038.73170410654, 1133.5322919443, 1282.55216335243, 
> 1376.68748390712, 85.2373706436, 73.678351600224, 66.443569896816, 
> 145.444059761616, 233.25934112712, 243.570984014736, 259.537398808464, 
> 316.916701973424, 424.690001831088, 821.60509459392, 852.456864846384, 
> 942.18478965072, 1014.5326066848, 1048.71071335262, 0, 0.083158410384, 
> 0.498950462304, 2.0789602596, 2.328435490752, 7.48425693456, 
> 13.637979302976, 14.5527218172, 7.983207396864, 35.009690771664, 
> 39.5002449324, 40.248670625856, 46.15291776312, 46.236076173504, 
> 0, 0, 0, 2.0789602596, 2.328435490752, 7.48425693456, 13.637979302976, 
> 14.5527218172, 7.983207396864, 35.009690771664, 39.5002449324, 
> 40.248670625856, 46.15291776312, 46.236076173504, 85.2373706436, 
> 73.59519318984, 65.944619434512, 143.365099502016, 230.930905636368, 
> 236.086727080176, 245.899419505488, 302.363980156224, 416.706794434224, 
> 786.595403822256, 812.956619913984, 901.936119024864, 968.37968892168, 
> 1002.47463717912, 1.413692976528, 1.081059334992, 1.413692976528, 
> 62.701441429536, 79.0004898648, 72.763609086, 69.43727267064, 
> 73.844668420992, 82.825776742464, 142.61667380856, 148.02197048352, 
> 207.230758676928, 240.410964420144, 228.851945376768), grass = c(9190.16856517738, 
> 9156.98835943416, 9175.11689289787, 9125.97027236093, 8964.80927303674, 
> 8887.72142661077, 8838.99059812574, 8784.77131455538, 8732.79730806538, 
> 8289.81245594981, 8310.01994967312, 8133.80727806942, 8001.08645509656, 
> 7855.55923692456, 5029.33750161394, 4935.70113152155, 4919.23576626552, 
> 4846.47215717952, 4722.98191775928, 4660.03100109859, 4632.33925044072, 
> 4577.20522435613, 4490.72047755677, 4083.90953395824, 4090.06325632666, 
> 3941.45917697045, 3848.82070780267, 3776.9718412309, 983.015569149264, 
> 921.145711823568, 909.586692780192, 900.356109227568, 888.797090184192, 
> 850.045270945248, 833.829380920368, 830.004094042704, 846.96840976104, 
> 829.5051435804, 841.064162623776, 824.598797367744, 814.702946532048, 
> 800.981808818688, 710.255983089744, 665.932550355072, 662.024105067024, 
> 655.70406587784, 652.211412641712, 619.363840540032, 610.216415397792, 
> 603.064792104768, 619.031206898496, 600.40372297248, 609.218514473184, 
> 595.497376759824, 584.936258641056, 572.213021852304, 3726.66100294858, 
> 3713.85460774944, 3713.77144933906, 3654.72897796642, 3548.03673744374, 
> 3530.98926331502, 3529.07661987619, 3475.43944517851, 3370.99248173621, 
> 2983.72376457792, 2967.1752409115, 2838.52918004746, 2755.28761125307, 
> 2700.40306039963, 879.982298683488, 861.853765219776, 840.398895340704, 
> 802.561818615984, 776.366919345024, 771.793206773904, 772.458474056976, 
> 772.874266108896, 763.39420732512, 702.106458872112, 700.526449074816, 
> 620.943850337328, 590.00892167448, 597.410020198656), city = c(146.026168634304, 
> 157.834662908832, 158.499930191904, 158.084138139984, 163.572593225328, 
> 169.975790824896, 171.638959032576, 175.713721141392, 178.624265504832, 
> 182.200077151344, 184.61167105248, 189.434858854752, 189.268542033984, 
> 200.910719487744, 146.026168634304, 157.834662908832, 158.499930191904, 
> 158.084138139984, 163.572593225328, 169.975790824896, 171.638959032576, 
> 175.713721141392, 178.624265504832, 182.200077151344, 184.61167105248, 
> 189.434858854752, 189.268542033984, 200.910719487744, 141.119822421648, 
> 152.928316696176, 153.593583979248, 153.260950337712, 158.749405423056, 
> 165.152603022624, 166.73261281992, 170.807374928736, 173.717919292176, 
> 176.378988424464, 178.457948684064, 183.530611717488, 183.36429489672, 
> 194.840155529712, 141.119822421648, 152.928316696176, 153.593583979248, 
> 153.260950337712, 158.749405423056, 165.152603022624, 166.73261281992, 
> 170.807374928736, 173.717919292176, 176.378988424464, 178.457948684064, 
> 183.530611717488, 183.36429489672, 194.840155529712, 4.906346212656, 
> 4.906346212656, 4.906346212656, 4.823187802272, 4.823187802272, 
> 4.823187802272, 4.906346212656, 4.906346212656, 4.906346212656, 
> 5.82108872688, 6.153722368416, 5.904247137264, 5.904247137264, 
> 6.070563958032, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), soil = c(61.12143163224, 
> 41.828680423152, 67.77410446296, 42.660264526992, 21.538028289456, 
> 34.760215540512, 36.090750106656, 48.23187802272, 75.25836139752, 
> 63.034075071072, 58.543520910336, 68.522530156416, 70.352015184864, 
> 67.940421283728, 61.12143163224, 41.828680423152, 67.025678769504, 
> 39.583403342784, 21.039077827152, 34.09494825744, 35.508641233968, 
> 44.90554160736, 63.117233481456, 59.208788193408, 54.551917211904, 
> 65.029876920288, 66.776203538352, 62.451966198384, 50.144521461552, 
> 33.67915620552, 30.934928662848, 29.438077275936, 15.301147510656, 
> 24.9475231152, 28.357017940944, 36.506542158576, 46.485551404656, 
> 48.23187802272, 46.402392994272, 56.630877471504, 59.87405547648, 
> 54.801392443056, 49.146620536944, 32.764413691296, 30.269661379776, 
> 28.772809992864, 14.5527218172, 23.949622190592, 27.359117016336, 
> 35.425482823584, 44.572907965824, 46.069759352736, 45.071858428128, 
> 54.46875880152, 57.711936806496, 52.639273773072, 9.895850835696, 
> 7.650573755328, 35.591799644352, 10.145326066848, 5.737930316496, 
> 9.14742514224, 7.151623293024, 8.398999448784, 16.6316820768, 
> 10.477959708384, 7.650573755328, 8.398999448784, 6.902148061872, 
> 7.650573755328, 6.320039189184, 6.320039189184, 32.348621639376, 
> 6.65267283072, 2.411593901136, 5.987405547648, 4.1579205192, 
> 3.575811646512, 5.987405547648, 4.407395750352, 2.744227542672, 
> 1.496851386912, 0.997900924608, 1.164217745376), water = c(9.230583552624, 
> 10.394801298, 8.066365807248, 7.317940113792, 7.151623293024, 
> 7.401098524176, 7.567415344944, 7.151623293024, 7.90004898648, 
> 8.149524217632, 7.983207396864, 7.733732165712, 8.066365807248, 
> 7.983207396864, 9.230583552624, 10.394801298, 8.066365807248, 
> 7.317940113792, 7.151623293024, 7.401098524176, 7.567415344944, 
> 7.151623293024, 7.90004898648, 8.149524217632, 7.983207396864, 
> 7.733732165712, 8.066365807248, 7.983207396864, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
> 0, 0, 7.401098524176, 8.648474679936, 6.818989651488, 6.65267283072, 
> 6.569514420336, 6.818989651488, 6.985306472256, 6.486356009952, 
> 6.569514420336, 6.818989651488, 6.65267283072, 6.569514420336, 
> 6.320039189184, 6.320039189184, 5.654771906112, 6.403197599568, 
> 4.740029391888, 4.656870981504, 4.57371257112, 4.906346212656, 
> 5.072663033424, 4.324237339968, 4.490554160736, 4.57371257112, 
> 4.490554160736, 4.57371257112, 4.490554160736, 4.490554160736
> )), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
> -84L), groups = structure(list(station = c("F01", "F02", "F03", 
> "F04", "F05", "F06"), .rows = structure(list(1:14, 15:28, 29:42, 
>     43:56, 57:70, 71:84), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
> "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
> ), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .drop = TRUE))
> ```